# Bokeh - Adding line pattern fill to a plot

Tags: python, bokeh

I was looking everywhere but so far haven't been able to figure out how to solve this. So far, I have a plot like this one:

[image: Current plot]

The problem is that the section in the middle actually overlaps with the dark green one. As I want to clearly point this out, I was thinking on creating some kind of line filling. To give you an idea of what I want, see following graph:

[image]

I know that a way around would be to create the lines one by one, but this seems somewhat of an overkill. Dear bokeh lovers, are you aware of a more direct way to achieve this?

Comment: It seems that to provide a fill pattern, canvas, or hatching requires the creation of a bokeh extension. For example, bokeh does not have the matplotlib equivalent of hatch at the moment. But this wwould be particularly useful for me--my boss is colorblind. https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/hatch_demo.html

Answer (score 1):

As of Bokeh `0.13.0`, this is still an open feature request: [`#6135` **Feature request: Textures to fill properties?**](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/6135)

Comment: Thank you  for letting me know. Looking forward to the release :)